# Get Dynamic Component Presentation in DXA 2.0 like DD4T

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, sites-9.1, .net

I am trying to fetch the DCP in DXA .NET application. I found some link where it has been mentioned to use
`ContentProvider.GetEntityModel()` but it takes a `Localization` as input. So always it takes the publication ID of the Publication where the Web url is linked.

My requirement is to fetch the DCP from other Publications as well, like `ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponent(componentTcmId, CTTcmId);` Where I can instantiate `ComponentPresentationFactory` with respective Publication ID?

Or is there any way to customize the `WebRequestContext` to point to other web Publication dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebRequestContext.Localization` is indeed the context Localization/Publication per definition.

However, you can obtain other Localizations using `SiteConfiguration.LocalizationResolver.GetLocalization()`; it takes the Localization ID (i.e. the first number from the TCM URI) as input.

You can then pass in the obtained `Localization` object to the `GetEntityModel` method.

Comment: This fits more as per my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

DXA is built on top of DD4T, so the underlying APIs are the same. We should be able to use the standard Content Delivery API to get DCPs. Using the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` class and passing the publication ID in the constructor, we should be able to get DCPs based on publications. Something like this should work:

```
ComponentPresentationAssembler componentPresentationAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(19);
String content = componentPresentationAssembler.getContent(2049, 2050);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want the result as Component class .This will provide the output as a string and then I have to transform the string into proper format.

Comment: The result is a JSON. So not a big effort to serialize the string. Thanks